# MVVM Light “Type Not Found in cache”

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop, mvvm-light

Я пытаюсь реализовать Drag and Drop с помощью MVVM Light и RelayCommand,но при запуске вылетает исключение Additional information: Type not found in cache: Puzzle.ViewModel.Drop.

мой ViewModel.Drop.

```
public Drop(Fragment frag)
{
    if (frag == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Image");
    _frag = frag;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Image");

}

private Fragment _frag;
public Bitmap Image
{
    get
    {
        if (_frag != null)
            return _frag.Pic;

        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        _frag.Pic = value;
    }

}

private RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> _ImageDrop;
public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> ImageDrop
{
    get
    {
        if (_ImageDrop == null)
            _ImageDrop = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(hatDropExecute);

        return _ImageDrop;
    }
}

private void hatDropExecute(DragEventArgs e)
{
    Fragment vm = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Fragment)) as Fragment;
    if (vm != null) return;
    _frag = vm;
    RaisePropertyChanged("Image");

}
```

Мой UserControl

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <med:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="bgnd" StartPoint="0 .5">
        <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="White" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="Gray" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>


    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="placement" StartPoint="0, 0">
        <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Transparent" />
        <GradientStop Offset="0.9" Color="White" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ImagePlacement" TargetType="Canvas">
        <!--<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="DragAndDrop"/>-->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=placement}" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Gold" GlowSize="5" />
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
        <!--<EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="DropImage" />
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown" />-->
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>





<Grid Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Width="300"
      Height="300">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Name="Canvas"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ImagePlacement}"
            Tag="1">
        <Image Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding HatMouseDown}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>-->
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ImageDrop}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
```

ViewModelLocator код

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    ////{
    ////    // Create design time view services and models
    ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
    ////}
    ////else
    ////{
    ////    // Create run time view services and models
    ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
    ////}
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Drop>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
}
public Drop drop
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance <Drop>();
    }
}
public MainViewModel Main
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}

public DragAndDrop drag
{
    get
    {
       return new DragAndDrop();
    }
}

public static void Cleanup()
{
    // TODO Clear the ViewModels
}
```

Comment: А вы зарегистрировали этот тип с помощью метода `SimpleIoc.Default.Register()`?

Comment: да,вставил код ViewModelLocator

Comment: А где собственно создается `ViewModelLocator`? Уверены, что конструктор вызывается?